# Convert Dictionary to anonymous object in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, anonymous-types, sqlkata

I have a web API I'm building in C#. This web API is used as a front end to query a SQL database. I am using SqlKata as the engine to perform the querying. When generating a WHERE clause, the SqlKata documentation states the following:

Multiple fields

If you want to filter your query against multiple fields, pass an object that represents col/values.

```
var query = new Query("Posts").Where(new {
    Year = 2017 ,
    CategoryId = 198 ,
    IsPublished = true,
});
```

I want to be able to avoid hardcoding the WHERE clause, but rather base it on passed in querystrings. My idea was to add each querystring name and value to a Dictionary then somehow use the values of that Dictionary within the SqlKata .Where() clause. I thought maybe I could convert the Dictionary to the required anonymous object, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas folks on how to do this? So my url might be:

https://webapi.com.au/api?store=120&name=james

Dictionary: 
store=120
name=james

Query: 
var query = new query("Posts").Where(anonObject)

( anonObject would be {store=120,name=james} )

Comment: If you're trying to "avoid hard-coding the WHERE clause" aren't you just shifting the hard-coding to a dictionary?

Comment: No, because the dictionary would be driven by the query strings the user would add to the URL of the web API. The idea was, that the user could add any combination of query string values which would correspond to columns in the table. That would be converted into the dictionary, then into the anonymous object. So effectively, by using querystring entries like store=120&user=james, this would end up being WHERE store = 120 AND user = james. But could just as easily be just store=120 which would result in only WHERE store = 120. The dictionary isn't hard coded, its dynamic based on querystrings

Comment: Why not just do a loop over the query string values and build up your query with successive .Where("column", "value") calls? Or extend the query to support taking an IDictionary<string, object> if it doesn't already?

Comment: This is incredibly dangerous with a high chance of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @JamesMatson - Your anonymous object would be driven by the query strings that the use would add to the URL. I just don't see the difference between the anonymous object and the dictionary. The only major differences would be the dynamic nature of the dictionary and the strong-typing of the anonymous object. But neither of those things change the "hard-coding" that you're trying to avoid - you're still working towards fulfilling a contract.

Comment: @ErikPhilips can you elaborate? I don't see how this is anymore vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack than any other use of SqlKata.

Comment: Where(Dictionary<string,object>) is supported natively https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/blob/master/QueryBuilder/Base.Where.cs#L80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an anonymous object. Looking at the SqlKata docs, you can just build up the query by looping over the dictionary, something like this:

```
//Assuming the dictionary is something like Dictionary<string, object>

var query = new Query("Posts");

foreach(var element in dictionary)
{
    query = query.Where(element.Key, element.Value);
}

var result = query.Get();
```

Note: Never even heard of SqlKata before so this is just from looking at the docs.

Comment: Thanks DavidG, that looks like it will do the trick. I am guessing your note is to demonstrate that I failed to review the documentation properly, but I will say that it was an honest mistake - i literally missed that particular section. Thanks for the point out, I'll give this a shot!